# How to use jQuery code in meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

so I can't make run `JQuery` code in meteor! I have added package `meteor add jquery`.

Solutions:
make jquery run in `meteor` **OR** convert JQuery code to JS code

Somebody knows how to solve it?

thanks a lot for your help!

*Example*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        accordion: false
    });
});
```

Comment: what does `console.log($)` output?

Comment: "convert JQuery code to JS code", you lost me there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly add the `jquery` package inside a Meteor project because it usually already includes packages depending on `jquery` (namely the templating packages).

However, you can't just copy `jQuery` code examples inside a Meteor app and expect them to work without a little bit of extra work : in particular you need to initialize `jQuery` plugins only when the corresponding DOM elements have been inserted in the DOM by Blaze, the Meteor template rendering engine.

Assuming that you have the following (MaterializeCSS) template markup :

```
<template name="collapsible">
  <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-image-filter-drama"></i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-maps-place"></i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-social-whatshot"></i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

You'll need to initialize the collapsible plugin inside an `onRendered` lifecycle event :

```
Template.collapsible.onRendered(function(){
  // we're using the template instance scoped jQuery
  this.$('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false
  });
});
```